# Bash script executing a binary

Tags: bash

I have a bash script that I am modifying. The script now also executes a binary. Say something like this
`mybin arg1 arg1` The binary takes about 5 minutes to execute and when I execute it from bash directly, it does show the intermediate outputs. When I add it to my script as

```
`mybin arg1 arg1`
```

I get the output in the end and bash thinks the output is a command and tries to execute it. So I want to solve 2 things

1. Show the intermediate output on the screen when I execute the binary from the bash script.
2. And the output must not be treated to be a command for processing, just regular output

Comment: Also note `$(...)` for *command substitution* serves the same purpose as *backticks* but is more readable. (oldengineer)-->

Comment: You may find [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) useful. It automatically points out this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the backticks.

`` `prog` `` means "collect the output of `prog` and interpolate it into the current command", so if `` `prog` `` is the only thing on the command line, its output will be executed as another command. This is known as [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution).

In other words, the two things you don't want to happen are exactly what `` ` ` `` is designed to do.

Comment: @curiousengineer I'm curious: Why did you think you needed the backticks in the first place? A shell script contains commands just like you'd normally type them.